# Alguien podría ayudarme en pasar este código de Pascal a C++ con hilos

Tags: c++

Alguien podría hacerme el gran favor de pasarme este  código a c++ o en todo caso explicarme cómo hacerlo, muchas gracias

```
program prog22;
var turno: integer;
Process P1;
begin
repeat
while turno=2 do
null; 
writeln('Proceso 1 ejecutando...'); 
turno:=2;
forever
end;
Process P2;
begin
repeat
while turno=1 do
null; 
writeln('Proceso 2 ejecutando...'); 
turno:=1;
forever
end;
begin
turno:=1;
cobegin
P1;
P2;
coend;
end.
```

ese sería todo el código, es respecto al algoritmo alternancia de dekker

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto. El código es un poco más complicado que el que pusiste tú para Pascal porque usa mutexes para escribir en la variable global:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;

int turno = 1;
bool es_turno_1() { return turno == 1; }
bool es_turno_2() { return turno == 2; }

void f1()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        cv.wait(lck, es_turno_1);  // espera a que el turno sea 1
        turno = 2;
        cv.notify_one();  // notifica a quien este esperando por un cambio de turno
    }
    std::cout << "Hilo 1 ejecutando...\n";
    for (;;)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        std::cout << ".";
    }
    std::cout << "Hilo 1 acabó.\n";
}

void f2()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        cv.wait(lck, es_turno_2);
        turno = 1;
        cv.notify_one();
    }
    std::cout << "Hilo 2 ejecutando...\n";
    for (;;)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        std::cout << "-";
    }
    std::cout << "Hilo 2 acabó\n";
}


int main()
{
    turno = 1;

    // Correr hilos
    std::thread t2(f2);
    std::thread t1(f1);

    // Hilos ejecutandose concurrentemente ahora

    // Esperar a que los hilos acaben
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, en caso de que quiera una alternancia estricta, o sea que vaya entre hilo1 y hilo2 sin ejecutar dos mismos hilos a la vez, eso es lo que necesito, es que yo sólo pude programar en pascal porque es lo que sé, en c++ estoy aprendiendo recién

Comment: Para eso puedes cambiar el código de la función que ejecuta cada hilo:
`std::cout << "Hilo 1 ejecutando...\n";
    for (;;)
    {
        // Esperamos nuestro turno
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        cv.wait(lck, es_turno_1);

        // Hacemos lo que sea
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        std::cout << ".";

        // Notificamos a quien este esperando por un cambio de turno
        turno = 2;
        cv.notify_one(); 
    }
    std::cout << "Hilo 1 acabó.\n";`